# Skip to Main Content link not working?

Tags: theming

The theme I'm using (AT Panels Everywhere subtheme for Adaptivetheme) has the following skip navigation link:

```
<div id="skip-link">  
<a href="#content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
```

but that link goes nowhere when I hit Enter when that div becomes focused as I tab through on the keyboard.

I tried adding the "content" anchor tag like this:

```
<div id="content" class="region">
<span style="width: 100%;" tabindex="0"><a name="content"></a></span>
<?php print $content; ?>
</div>
```

but it still doesn't work. I'm still forced to tab through every link on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code like this

```
<div id="content" class="region">
<span style="width: 100%;" tabindex="0"><a href="#content">Skip</a></span>
<?php print $content; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I'm not sure that's right. The code I mentioned above is for the anchor tag that is being linked by the 'Skip to main content' link in my site template which is this: <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>`